# Firebase realtime database transactions sometimes take too long to complete

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have a nodejs application which runs on a single server. I need to run the app on multiple servers for load balancing.

This app only handles a single request from a particular user at a time. If simultaneous requests received from a user, the requests are queued and executed one after another. This is done to keep the consistency of some data in database, which would get corrupted if simultaneous requests are handled by the app.

Since I am going to run the app on multiple servers, I need a way to prevent servers from handling simultaneous requests from a single user. to achieve this, I used firebase realtime database to build a distributed lock. Following is a simpler version of my code.

```
function lockUser(user) {
    return firebaseAdmin.database().ref('users/' + user + '/lock').transaction((currentData) => {
        if (currentData === null || currentData.lockTime === 0) {
            return {'lockTime': Date.now()};
        }
    }, null, false).then(async (result) => {
        if (result.committed) {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
        log.info('failed to lock ' + user + '. retrying.');
        await sleepFor(500);
        return lockUser(user, user, res);
    }).catch(async (reason) => {
        log.info('lock failed. ' + user + '. reason: ' + reason + '. retrying');
        await sleepFor(500);
        return lockUser(user, user, res);
    });
}

function unlockUser(user) {
    log.info('unlocking firebase lock. ' + user);
    firebaseAdmin.database().ref('users/' + user + '/lock').set({'lockTime': 0}, (error) => {
        if (error) {
            log.warn('failed to unlock ' + user + '. error: ' + util.inspect(error));
        } else {
            log.info('unlocked ' + user);
        }
    });
}
```

With above code, a lock usually takes about 100 milliseconds and it is mostly consistent. But rarely sometimes, I observe a significant delay to finish a transaction. When this happens, lock may take about 30 seconds.

What could be the reason for this delay? Is there any reason I shouldn't use firebase realtime database in this way?

Answer (score 1):

RTDB transactions are essentially compare-and-set operations. If the state of the database changes while a transaction is in progress, the SDK retries the transaction with the new state of the database. In your case this can happen when multiple processes contend for the lock:

1. P1 attempts to get the lock, sees `currentData.lockTime = 0`, and decides to update it.
2. P2 attempts to get the lock, sees `currentData.lockTime = 0`, and decides to update it.
3. P1 commits its transaction.
4. P2 sees that the data has changed since its last read, so it retries the transaction.

Now there's a pathological case where just before P2 retries the transaction, P1 gives up its lock. So P2 will again see that `currentData.lockTime = 0`, and try to grab the lock again. But this attempt too can fail if another process P3 grabs the lock from under P2. And so the retry loop continues.

In the worst case a transaction can get retried up to [25 times](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/6b53e0058483c9002d2fe56119f86fc9fb96b56c/packages/database/src/core/Repo_transaction.ts#L71).

I'm not certain if this is what's happening in your case. But that's definitely one explanation. Perhaps enable debug logging for the SDK, and try to get more insight to what's going on during these long delays. I would also recommend trying to implement your regular data update operations using transactions, and eliminating the distributed lock altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but lock contention doesn't seem to be the reason in this instance. My logs show that there were no other lock attempts when a single lock took abnormally high amount of time. Also, I have tested the lock by sending several client requests at once, and server manages to sequentially execute them pretty quickly (with the nature of my client app, simultaneous requests are rare, so I didn't test with a large number of simultaneous requests).

Comment: Another possibility is a server failover. The delay you see could be the time it takes for the SDK to detect a server failure, and failover to a different server in the pool (although ~30s sounds too high for that to be the case). SDK debug logs should be able to confirm.

Comment: Thanks. I will enable logs and try to figure out what is going wrong.